# Convert IEEE Double to Integer - Verilog

Tags: verilog, xilinx

I want to convert the IEEE Double value computed in my code to Integer.

E.g. I have computed:
X = 64'hxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
Now i want to use it as index of an array as:
some_array[X];

How can I do it? Is there any IP-Core or any other third-party Core for this conversion? Or some synthesis-able method/algorithm?

**EDIT**:- My number X between is 0~2601 which is valid range for my array, BUT it includes fractions and I only have to

a) convert the number from IEEE double into integer format, and

b) remove the fraction part (round it off).